# How to use personal certificate for WCF communication?

Tags: wcf, encryption, runtime, certificate, smartcard

When inserting a smart card to a reader the certificates will be read in to the personal store, my question is simple how I then explain for WCF that it should use a specific (of these) certificate in runtime?

My WCF service is selfhosted and are communicating with the client over TCP.

I do already have a communication that uses certificate but these certificates is stated in the config files(one for service and one for client).

Now I need to switch the certificate on the client side before communicating.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? And could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to find a specific set of attributes that is unique to the certificate you would like to use.
For example we use filtering like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the certificate we need for authentication
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>the certificate</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">when no certificate is available</exception>
    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        // open private certificate store of the user
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        // get the collection of certificates which we need
        X509Certificate2Collection certColl = store.Certificates
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByExtension, new X509KeyUsageExtension().Oid.Value, false)
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation, false);

        store.Close();
        // if more certificates match the criteria, let the user choose one
        if (certColl.Count > 1)
        {
            certColl = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                certColl, "Choose certificate", "We were unable to find the correct certificate. Please choose one from the list.",
                X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
        }
        // if no certificate is available, fail
        if (certColl.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No certificates selected");
        }
        else
        {
            return certColl[0];
        }
    }
```

Check the attributes of the certificates you need and try to create your own Find criteria. Of course the use could have additional certificates in his store which match the criteria, this case a dialog window pops up and asks the user to do this himself.

Of course once the user chooses the correct certificate you can store the CN of the certificate in the application configuration file so next time he won't have to do these steps again.